# Map an object key and values back in a table? REACT and HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have to render a table based on how many keys are in an object. I got the table headers to render the keys fine as values for that column however i have no idea how to do this for each array to map the value of that key for the table row. React just says object with keys cannot be children please use an array.

i pointed to the first array of roles for the titles

```
 {roles && Object.keys(roles[0])?.map((x: any, n: any) => (
                <th
                  scope="col"
                  className="">
                  <p
                    onClick={() => sortTable(n)}
                    className="group flex justify-between items-center">
                    {x}
                    {sortIndex == n ? (
                      <ChevronDownIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
                    ) : (
                      <ChevronUpIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
                    )}
                  </p>
                </th>
    ))}
```

Currently i have each property in a line

```
 {roles?.map((role: any, index: any) => (
  <tr key={index}>
   {role?.userId && (
    <td className="py-2 px-3 text-lg text-gray-900">{role.userId}</td>
    )}
  </tr>))}
```

is there a way to map the values in based on the keys i did for titles??? reasoning for this is some array will have 4 keys and some will have 12 i would ideally like to not have up to 12 tds checked at all times for a value.

Perhaps my whole approach is wrong too! any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose the following solution.

[Working stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rbp3tv?file=App.tsx)

I have stripped out the sorting, since it is not part of the question. I have used functional components. All components are divided so that the can be tested separately if needed

```js
interface TableHeaderProps {
  sampleRow: Record<string, any>;
}

const TableHeader = (props: TableHeaderProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {Object.keys(props.sampleRow).map((key, index) => (
        <th scope="col" className="" key={key}>
          <p className="group flex justify-between items-center">{key}</p>
        </th>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};

interface TableRowProps {
  row: Record<string, any>;
}

const TableRow = (props: TableRowProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {Object.keys(props.row).map((key) => (
        <td key={key} className="py-2 px-3 text-lg text-gray-900">
          {props.row[key]}
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};

interface TableProps {
  rows: Array<Record<string, any>>;
}

export const Table = (props: TableProps): JSX.Element => {
  // if we do not have y data we cannot render even the header
  if (!props.rows || props.rows.length === 0) {
    return <div> No data to show</div>;
  }
  return (
    <table>
      <TableHeader sampleRow={props.rows[0]} />
      {props.rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow row={row} />
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};
```

Sample usage:

```js
const cars = [
  {
    registrationNr: 'BA12355',
    make: 'Audi',
    model: 'S8',
    modelYear: 2015,
    milage: 30000,
  },
  {
    registrationNr: 'SS22345',
    make: 'Mercedec',
    model: 'S500',
    modelYear: 2011,
    milage: 50000,
  },
];

...
<Table rows={cars} />
...
```

Comment: HUGE help! Thank you!!! I was just off a tad on my other attempts.